# Keyboard hooking

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, keyboard-hook

I'm trying to write in c program which analyzes statistically the using of some keyboard keys.
First I want to create a keylogger using global hook and log it to file.

Here is the first part of the code i wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

HHOOK hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK hook_proc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdstruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        char ch = kbdstruct.vkCode;
        printf("%c", ch);

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


void main()
{
    MSG msg;
    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HOOKPROC(hook_proc), NULL, 0);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }
}
```

1. Why do I have to create Infinite loop? it doesnt work without it.
2. I read that for global hook the second parameter in `SetWindowHookEx` should point to the hook procedure in EXTERNAL DLL. It works fine that why only printing the virtual code. How do I convert it to "regular keys" without switch case for every virtual key? Is there a effective way?
3. If an external dll is required how should it be written and called from the main based on the code I wrote?

Comment: There is no keyboard in C.

Comment: This question seems to be three questions. Therefore I consider it to be "*too broad*".

Comment: 1: the operating system has to break into your program to make the hook_proc() call.  It only does that when your main thread can be safely interrupted to make the call.  GetMessage() is the universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  2: WH_KEYBOARD_LL is special, it doesn't require a DLL.

Comment: I also stuck with 2-nd problem before (while writing my own spy program), and the most elegant solution that I found so far is... Implement your own keyboard driver and somehow programmically put it into your client's system (or victim's system :D). If you understand russian then I can give you some link to a tutorial in russian language.

Comment: What's infinite about `while(<expression that can evaluate to false>)`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a message loop to process the keyboard activity. This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx):

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, **the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop**.

2. *Most* global hooks run in the context of each running process, so the hook must be in a DLL so it can be injected into other processes. But not `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` (see above).  As for the keys themselves, `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` provides only *virtual keys* and *scan codes*. To convert them into characters, use [`MapVirtualKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306.aspx), [`MapVirtualKeyEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646307.aspx), [`ToUnicode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320.aspx), or [`ToUnicodeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646322.aspx).
3. A DLL is not required for `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. See above.